# same HTTP methods on same endpoint are not showing

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am creating swagger for my APIs but I have an issue for same endpoints having same methods. Here are two same endpoints (/token) with same `httpMethod POST` and both have different parameters in the body. On UI swagger not showing the first endpoint.

**This is my swagger code:**

```
"/token": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Authorisation"
        ],
        "summary": "Get Token by Username and Password",
        "operationId": "6bfe7ad3-64e8-4550-8fc9-c93ff30f4f0e",
        "consumes": [
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
        "parameters": [
                  ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/getTokenResponse"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "basic_auth": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Authorisation"
        ],
        "summary": "Refresh Acces Token",
        "operationId": "6bfe7ad3-64e8-4550-8fc9-c93ff30f4f0e",
        "consumes": [
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
        "parameters": [
                 ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/getTokenResponse"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "basic_auth": []
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Each HTTP method can only be used once per path. You cannot have two POSTs for the same path. There's a corresponding [feature request](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/182) in the OpenAPI Specification repository.

What you can do is convert your API definition to OpenAPI 3.0, which supports `oneOf` and `anyOf` to define alternative payloads for the same operation:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /token:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/getTokenRequest'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/refreshTokenRequest'
```

but in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 it's not possible.